# Set Featured Image Front Frontend Form

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments, forms, front-end

I have been struggling for days to figure this one out. I have successfully implemented a form to submit posts from the front end of my site. ButI can't figure out how to make the image uploads work.

I want whatever image the user uploads to automatically attach to the post and become its featured image.

Can someone please explain how to do this with my existing code?

I have searched through all relevant questions on this forum and none of the solutions work for me.

```
                <?

            if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['insert_post'] )) { //check that our form was submitted
            //If it has, redirect to the dashboard
            ?><script language="javascript"><!--
            location.replace("/dashboard/")
            //-->
            </script> <?php

            $title = $_POST['thread_title']; //set our title

            if ($_POST['thread_description']=="") { // check if a description was entered
            $description = "See thread title..."; // if not, use placeholder
            } else {
            $description = $_POST['thread_description']; //if so, use it
            }

            $tags = $_POST['thread_tags']; //load thread tags (custom tax) into array

            $post = array( //our wp_insert_post args
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($title),
            'post_content'  => $description,
            'post_category' => array('0' => $_POST['cat']),
            'tax_input' => array('thread_tag' => $tags),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'tsv_userpost'
            );

            $my_post_id = wp_insert_post($post); //send our post, save the resulting ID

            $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); //check who is logged in

            add_post_meta($my_post_id, '_your_custom_meta', $var); //add custom meta data, after the post is inserted


            } else {

            if(is_user_logged_in()) { // check that the user is logged in before presenting form

            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

            ?>

            <div id="postbox">

            <form id="new_thread" name="new_thread" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input class="required" type="text" id="thread_title" value="" tabindex="1" name="thread_title" placeholder="Thread Title" />

            <textarea id="thread_description" name="thread_description" cols="80" rows="20" tabindex="2"></textarea>

            <div class="left">
            <select name='cat' id='cat' class='postform required' tabindex="3">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Choose:</option>
            <option class="writing" value="90">Writing</option>
            <option class="image" value="91">Image</option>
            <option class="video" value="92">Video</option>
            <option class="audio" value="94">Audio</option>
            <option class="link" value="95">Link</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="4" size="16" name="thread_tags" id="thread_tags" placeholder="Tags" />
            <br />

            <!-- images -->
            <label for="images">Featured Image:</label>
            <input type="file" name="user-image-featured" id="user-image-featured" size="20">
            <!-- Submit button-->
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Save Post" tabindex="5" id="thread_submit" name="thread_submit" class="thread-button" />

            <input type="hidden" name="insert_post" value="post" />

            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new_thread' ); ?>

            </form>

            </div>

            <?php } else { echo 'please login'; } } ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do that by running the function

```
set_post_thumbnail( $my_post_id, $thumbnail_id );
```

remember, you have to process and insert the image into the library first:

```
$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$file = $_FILES[ ... whatever you have in your POST data ... ];
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file );

move_uploaded_file( $file , $uploadfile );
$filename = basename( $uploadfile );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
```

did not test the script - it is adapted from a version i created. maybe you want to change the filename and stuff like that, but all in all it works this way :)

Comment: Thanks! I've played with similar functions to that one with no luck. Am I just putting the code in the wrong place? Where should those two code snippets go in the code above?

Comment: this doesn't really matter. you can create the post before the attachment or the other way round, the only important thing is to have both created when you call `set_post_thumbnail( $my_post_id, $thumbnail_id );`

Comment: by the way, your image is submitted correctly? try `print_r( $_FILES )` to see if you got the right setup and the image available.

Answer (score 1):

/******* This is working for me ! ********/

```
$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$file = $_FILES["post_Fimage"]["name"];
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file );

move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["post_Fimage"]["tmp_name"] , $uploadfile );
$filename = basename( $uploadfile );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is working correctly !

```
$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$file = $_FILES["post_Fimage"]["name"];
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file );

move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["post_Fimage"]["tmp_name"] , $uploadfile );
$filename = basename( $uploadfile );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($wp_filetype);echo "</pre>";
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES);echo "</pre>";
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I fix your code ?

```
$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$file = $_FILES[ ... whatever you have in your POST data ... ];
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file['name'] );

move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] , $uploadfile );
$filename = basename( $uploadfile );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: sorry, the $_FILES have some field like ["name"] and ["tmp_name"] that must be used otherwise not work the file uploading

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try checking the recapcha box first if you are using recapcha.  The recapcha will prevent any post or get