# Upload image without media-upload

Tags: images, uploads

I've been looking a while and didnt found: How to create simple, old, good, upload via 'Browse' button and 'Dir' field that will upload and return image url.

I dont want to use media-upload.

Would be nice to use wordpress image functions like croping, checking size etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an answer I gave [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72406/set-featured-image-front-frontend-form/72411#72411). You will still have to build the form yourself - but that should not be a problem.